# How to scratch Android studio / SDK / ADB etc from disk (for reinstallation)

Tags: 18.04, android, android-studio

I somehow messed up my android studio configuration. At least "adb" is not working anymore, which leads to the fact that I cannot see my connected phone for USB debugging.

Adb gives a "permission denied" and following the respective stackoverflow recommendations did not solve my problem (installing 32bit libraries, downloading older Android Studio version, chmod +x on adb)

Now I just want a clean new installation. But even that ends in the same error.

I already deleted 2 folders in my home directory (.android and .AndroidStudio4.0)

**Update**
I could at least install Android adb globally using

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

which works inside the console and also lists my connected phone. However back in Android studio the phone is still not listed for debugging

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing && sudo apt-get install -f`? This finds missing dependencies and broken packages and forces their installation. I was writing more, but fat finger hit post on mobile =|

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed my setup. The steps involve

```
sudo apt-get remove android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

then again delete

```
/home/user/.android
/home/user/.AndroidStudio4.0
```

My hunch is that the real culprit was that my android Sdk folder was not installed on my home partition

```
/home/user/Android
```

Instead I used a symbolic link to point to some larger partition (This setup used to work fine in the past, however).

Sorry for the unenlightening answer